# Importing an excel file in RStudio

Tags: r

Actually, I'm having trouble with importing a CSV file in my script in Rstudio. I am trying:

```
d <- read.table(file="table1.csv",sep="\t",header=T)
```

but it says that there is an error in file and "rt".

Comment: Wait, is it csv, xls, xlsx, or something else? If csv, use `read.csv`. If xlsx, check out [readxl](https://github.com/hadley/readxl) or similar packages.

Comment: It's csv... Here is the error message : d <- read.csv(file="TacheVigilance_s1.csv",sep="\t",header=TRUE)
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'TacheVigilance_s1.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: Apparently your filepath is incorrect. Also, you shouldn't use `sep = "\t"` if it's comma separated.

Comment: Is "TacheVigilance_s1.csv" located inside your `getwd()`? Try passing the absolute path as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

1. Type 'getwd()' in the console. If what returns isn't the same path as the file you're trying to read in, change this with `setwd("[your filepath here]")`. If you want a graphical solution instead, you can use the Set As / Go To Working Directory commands under the 'More' menu in RStudio's Files viewer (bottom right window).
2. Then try `d <- read.csv("table1.csv")`